# Issues with php nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Basically I'm using this library someone put together to return information from my minecraft server.  Everything works, except for this page I just want to list the mods and their version numbers.  You can see the output here:  http://litcraft.net/view2.php

As you can see, it's just using a loop to dump the information to the page.  All I'm trying to do is go into the last array "modinfo" and ONLY pint out the modid and version in a list.  I can format it once I get it, but I'm having an issue printing that list.  Here is the code for what there is now:

```
<?php foreach( $Info as $InfoKey => $InfoValue ): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=htmlspecialchars($InfoKey); ?></td>
        <td><?php
if($InfoKey === 'favicon'){
    echo '<img width="64" height="64" src="' . Str_Replace("\n","",$InfoValue) . '">';
}else if(Is_Array($InfoValue)){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($InfoValue);
    echo "</pre>";
}else{
    echo htmlspecialchars( $InfoValue );
}
?></td>
                </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So I tried to do this to dig into the array and print out only the mod list:

```
<?php 
$len = count($Info['modinfo']['modList']) + 1;
echo "<p>There are " . $len . " mods.</p>";
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
    foreach($Info['modinfo']['modlist'][$i] as $ModID => $ModVersion): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$ModID; ?></td>
                    <td><?=$ModVersion; ?></td>
                </tr>
    <?php endforeach;
}?>
```

And all I get is the error you see on the page 175 times....  What am I doing wrong?  I know it has to be something simple, but it's all starting to blend together at this point lol.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Can you supply a formatted `print_r` of the `$Info` array? It would help us understand the array structure and get an idea of what you are doing. If it is long, you can shorten it to like 2 or three entries. Also, be sure to remove any private/personal information.

Comment: undefined index 'modlist'.  That means there isn't a key 'modlist' in the array, but you ask for it in your loop, therefor the hundreds of errors.  And that's also why you're getting the foreach error.

Comment: You should check for isset($Info['modinfo']['modList']) && is_numeric($Info['modinfo']['modList']) before taking the count of it

Comment: do print_r or var_dump of $Info and there may be a lot of instances where 'modlist' isn't set.  Using isset as suggested above, or array_key_exists before using those values will help.

Comment: RightClick had it, the index was modList, I put modlist.  Thanks for catching it!  Told you I've been staring at it for too long.

Sachin - why would I need to check if it's numeric?  I'm counting how many are in the array, not doing any sort of math function with the information in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do instead of foreach

```
echo $Info['modinfo']['modlist'][$i]['modid'] ;
echo $Info['modinfo']['modlist'][$i]['version'] ;
```